# Check if size "40" is in stock on this website and send Discord message

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, discord

I'm trying to make the bot send discord messages when size 40 comes back in stock. I've tried to use this code for such things before, but I don't now where in the HTML I can check if the shoes are in stock in size 40.

```
 stock_element = soup.find('li', {'class': 'unselectable'})
```

I don't really understand how to make this part of the code find the specific element that tells if it's in stock.

https://www.courir.com/fr/p/ugg-tasman-1499533.html

Here is the code I've tried:

```
import discord
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import aiohttp
import asyncio

webhook_url = 'DISCORD API'

async def send_webhook_message(content):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(webhook_url, json={"content": content}) as response:
            if response.status == 204:
                print("Discord message sent successfully.")
            else:
                print(f"Error sending Discord message. Status code: {response.status}")

async def check_stock(url, size):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.raise_for_status()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        stock_element = soup.find('li', {'class': 'unselectable'})

        # Check if the stock_element is found and is not disabled
        return stock_element is not None and 'Size Variations' not in stock_element.attrs

    except requests.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error making request to the website: {e}")
        return False

product_data = [
    {'url': 'https://www.courir.com/fr/p/ugg-tasman-1499533.html', 'size': 'tasman'},
]
async def main():
    previous_stock_status = {}  # Dictionary to store previous stock status for each product

    while True:
        result_message = ""

        for product_info in product_data:
            url = product_info['url']
            size = product_info['size']
            current_stock_status = await check_stock(url, size)

            # Check if the product was out of stock in the previous check and is now in stock
            if not previous_stock_status.get(url, {}).get(size, False) and current_stock_status:
                result_message += f"({size}) is now in stock\n"

            previous_stock_status.setdefault(url, {})[size] = current_stock_status

        # Check if the result message is not equal to the specific message you want to avoid
        if result_message.strip() != "(NAVY S) is now in stock\n(NAVY M) is now in stock\n(NAVY L) is now in stock!\n(BEIGE S) is now in stock!\n(BEIGE M) is now in stock!\n(BEIGE L) is now in stock!":
            # Print the result message
            print(result_message)

            # Send Discord message only if there are updates
            if result_message:
                await send_webhook_message(result_message)
                print("Sent Discord message.")

        # Sleep for a certain interval (e.g., 10 minutes) before checking again
        print("10 min before next check")
        await asyncio.sleep(200)  # sleep for 10 minutes

# Run the main function asynchronously
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking for 'class': 'unselectable' only tells if the product is *not* in-stock. When it becomes available, it will instead be 'selectable'.

We'll use the inspector, (CTRL-SHIFT-I) in Firefox or Chrome, to get an idea of what attributes to search for. In this case, finding an anchor, of class 'swatchanchor' with a title that contains '40'. Whose parent is of class='selectable' would tell us that it was in-stock. Ordinarily, something like this might work.

```
size_40_available = soup.find('li', class_='selectable').find_all('a', class_='swatchanchor', title__contains='40')
```

But the problem is, the elements we are looking for are not in the page source. They are dynamically-generated by JavaScript. We won't be able to find them using traditional web scraping methods like Beautiful Soup or Scrapy. Instead, we may need to use a headless browser like Puppeteer or Selenium to interact with the page and extract the desired elements.

Answer (score 0):

> *.. but I don't know **where** in **the HTML** I can check if the shoes are in stock in size 40.*

It seems like this one is loaded by *JavaScript:*

```
url = "https://www.courir.com/fr/p/ugg-tasman-1499533.html"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N)"
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
}

payload = {
    "frz-smartcache-fragment": "true",
    "frz-timeout": "5000",
    "frz-smartcache-v": "2",
    "frz-smartcache-placeholders-number": "8"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload)

soup = BeautifulSoup(re.search(r"(<.*>)", r.text)
            .group().replace("\\", ""), "html.parser")

sizes = {}

for tag in soup.select("[class$='selectable']"):
    sizes.setdefault(tag["class"][0], []).append(
        tag.select_one("a").get_text().strip("n"))
```

Output:

```
print(sizes)

# {'unselectable': ['40'], 'selectable': ['41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46']}
```

If you only want to trigger the bot when the size `40` is available, you can do:

```
available_sizes = [
    tag["title"].split(": ")[-1]
    for tag in soup.select(".selectable a")
] # ['41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46']

if "40" in available_sizes:
    ...
```